# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (25,1) into shape (25)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, valueerror

when I am trying to run this simple snippet of code

```python
a= 2

G = np.random.rand(25,1)
H = np.zeros((25,a))

for i in range(a):
    H[:,i] = .5 * G
```

I receive the

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (25,1) into shape (25).
```

I wonder if anyone can point at a solution to this problem?

I know it happens quite a bit in image processing, but this one, I don't knwo how to circumvent.

Cheers.

Comment: Why did you choose that shape for G?

Answer (score 4):

To fix this you use the first column of G:

```
for i in range(a):
    H[:,i] = .5 * G[:, 0]
```

Numpy broadcasting basically attempts to match dimensions of arrays (when broadcasting) by starting with the last dimension and moving to the first. In this case the second dimension of G (1) gets broadcast to 25 (the first and only dimension of `H[:, i]`. The first dimension of G does not match with anything. You can read more about numpy broadcasting rules [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

**Note:** you really don't need that `for` loop. `H` is just `G` column repeated twice. You can accomplish that in various ways (e.g. [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html), [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html), etc.)

```
H = np.tile(G / 2, 2)
```